# What does the null hypothesis $H_0:\beta_2=0$ mean?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

For the model $$Y=\beta_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\epsilon$$ what does the null hypothesis $H_0:\beta_2=0$ mean?

I think that then $X_2$ would not affect the expected value of $Y$ since the coefficient os then $0$.

But is that correct?

Comment: Even more, in this case, $Y$ is independent of $X_2$ , so the value of $X_2$ does not matter at all.

Comment: Correct, this will be a test of whether $X_2$ affects the value $Y$.  If you do not get a good answer here, you could try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. If $\beta_3$ is 0, the variable has no predictive value for the response. No matter what value $X_2$ has, it does not alter the predicted value of the response.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)